# Windows | проверить наличие работоспособного USB

Tags: windows, usb

Добрый день,

Вопрос несколько странен, но возможно ли как-то в Windows, проверить работает ли USB (т.е. возможно ли подключение USB носителей). Это может быть команда, ветка реестра или еще что-нибдуь, что можно будет распарсить потом любым скриптовым языком.

На части компов USB закрыт в BIOS, на части сторонним софтом, на части все открыто. Хочу выяснить эти компы.

Answer (score 1):

Есть идея для пробы - это сканировать устройства на наличие USB-портов, если они есть и включены, то USB доступен. Это можно сделать двумя способами:

1. с помощью утилиты командной строки [devcon.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272/ru),
2. с помощью [запроса WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394587(v=vs.85).aspx) из скрипта.

Comment: Ай спасибо.. завтра буду пробовать, но вроде само то!